# Find out by how many shortest path curves a vertex is used

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm using Geometry Nodes `Shortes Edge Paths` + `Edge Paths to Curves` to create some guide curves for a hair model. On the source mesh I have end points on the outer border only while all other vertices are starting points. That results in many vertices are used by several curves. That is fine but it would be extremely helpful for the next step if it would be possible to find out for each vertex (more precisely: for each curve's root) by how many shortest edge paths it has been used (this would help to reduce hair density in some parts where it has no or very little visual effect).

I don't see how this could work, but would be very happy if someone could prove me wrong and show me a solution. Ah, and it has to be fast, because the number of guide curves created is already quite high.

BTW: I'm using 4.0.0 alpha already because a bug in 3.6.x, which so far is only fixed there, forces me to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**
While looking at it again after a while I found out that it is actually possible to achieve exactly what I wanted. It works as follows:

1. For each point (vertex) of the original mesh capture its index
2. Create the shortest path curves (many points are used by several splines)
3. Convert to points (`Curves to Points` with method `Evaluated`)
4. Use the new `Points to Curves` (Blender 4.0.0) node to sort points according to the original mesh vertex index (captured above)
5. Capture the new point index for each control point
6. Use `Delete Geometry` (or `Separate Geometry`) to delete every control point

   1. if the next point (index+1) belongs to the same original mesh vertex
   2. and in a second copy if the previous point (index-1) belongs to the same original mesh vertex
7. Now we have two curves with exactly one control point for each original mesh vertex in the same order as in the original mesh
8. For each vertex of the original mesh we can calculate the number of curves using that point by the difference between the lowest and highest index (from step 6.)

If it is not guaranteed that all vertices are actually used by at least one spline, then all original mesh vertices can be joined in the points created in step 3. by `Join Geometry` (afterwards such points need special treatment to avoid counting them as 1 spline using that vertex).

In my case I want to find the point which is used by the least other curves for each curve. That can be done by

1. Another sorting run (`Points to Curves`) such that we get one curve per original curve with all its original points but this time sorted by the number of curves using each point (from the previous step)
2. By deleting all but the point used by the smallest number of curves (which is the last point of each curve if sorted in descending order), we get again one point per curve with the value we are interested in
3. In my case I take that for curves derived from the curves used above (but resampled, such that they have other control points)

[image]

**Example:** I'm using that to create more hair curves especially next to the parting area by using the value calculated above to create the `Amount` input field for a `Duplicate Hair Curves` node.

[image]

It might be possible to simplify that by using the new `Repeat Zone` but I did not try that yet.